# Solving the puppet cube without preserving the shape

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, twisty-puzzles

I'm looking for a simple way of solving the [MoYu Puppet cube](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/MoYu#MoYu_Puppet_Cube) (version 2 to be precise). It's a shapemod of a 3x3 Rubik's cube on which 7 of 8 corners have additional parts which form a bigger 2x2 cube around the 3x3 cube. These parts effectively act as bandages, preventing certain moves on the inner 3x3 cube.

I've found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MChiNMvtLLI) where the Puppet cube is solved by first making it into a square shape, and then using formulas which preserve the shape during the entire process. Obviously, these formulas are much larger than those for a classic cube.

Is there a known way of solving the Puppet cube using formulas closer to those for the original Rubik's cube, that doesn't necessarily preserve the shape throughout the solution?